# Vue3 / How to pass data from mixin setup() to component

Tags: vue.js, components, vuejs3

I would like to pass my object based on JavaScript class from mixin to component without reactivity. I use TypeScript, so I can't set the object to `this` of mixin without setting types in data(). But data() reactivity breaks some thing in my object.

mixin.js:

```
export default {

  setup() {
    const foo = new Foo()
    
    return {
      foo,
    }
  }
    
}
```

component.js:

```
import mixin from './mixin.js'

export default {

  setup() {
    // How can I get foo here?
  }
  
}
```

### Update 1

Yes, it is good solution for using only one `foo` instance for everywhere.

But how can I use different `foo` instances for each component?

Same as in JS classes:

```js
class Mixin {
  foo() {
    // ...
  }
}

class Component extends Mixin {
  bar() {
    this.foo()
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, clarify how it's supposed to work. is `foo` instance unique to each component that uses it?

Comment: If it needs to be a different instance each time, you don't need a mixin. You just go `const foo = new Foo()` in the components where you need it. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mixin.js**

```js
export const foo = new Foo()
```

Import (and use) `foo` anywhere in your app, including any `setup()` function:

```js
import { foo } from './path/to/mixin'
```

---

The above uses the same instance everywhere. If you want to use different instances of `foo` in each separate component, **mixin.js**:

```js
export const useFoo = () => new Foo()
```

Anywhere else:

```
import { useFoo } from './path/to/mixin'
const foo = useFoo()
```

However, take note the second approach creates a new intance of Foo() every time `useFoo()` is called. So once you called it, you must use `foo` in that component.
Calling `useFoo()` multiple times in the same component will generate multiple instances, unlike how you'd use `useStore()`, for example.

---

But, I'm wondering, why do you need a mixin in the first place? Why not use:

```js
const foo = new Foo()
```

...in the components where you need it?
What are you trying to achieve? And, more importantly, *why*?

Comment: Tao, thanks!
I added Update1 to my question